# Перестановки С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика, перестановка

у меня вопрос по одному заданию которое я не очень могу понять, оно звучит так:

> Необходимо определить, существует ли перестановка длины n для заданных Si
> (
> i=1 ,2 ,…,n−1 ) — сумм ее соседних элементов (первого и второго, второго и третьего и так
> далее). Если существует, то вывести любую перестановку, обладающую вышеуказанным
> свойством, иначе вывести −1

> Вход
> 9
> 9 11 8 13
> 12 9 6 12

> Выход 6 3 9 2 7 1 5 8 4

Я понял что сначала мы должны задать `int n`, и инициализировать динамический массив размера `n-1`, после чего ввести элементы массива, и разложить их так что бы при выходе мы получили что-то такое

*Элемент1 + Элемент2 = первому числу вводимого массива*

*Элемент2 + Элемент3 = второму числу вводимого массива*

И так далее, условно должна получится вот такая схемка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я более менее понимаю как положить в массив элементы сумм первого массива, но не понимаю как получить в коде вот такую схему, приведенную выше, помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* swapN = new int[n - 1];
    int* finalArray = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> swapN[i];
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        finalArray[k] = swapN[k] + swapN[k + 1];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << finalArray[j] << endl;
    }




    delete[]finalArray;
    delete[]swapN;
}
```

**Дополнение к заданию**

> В первой строке дано число n ( 3≤n≤1000 ) — количество элементов в искомой перестановке.
> Во второй строке даны Si
> для i=1,3 , 5, ... — суммы элементов искомой перестановки: первого
> и второго, третьего и четвертого, и так далее. В третьей строке даны Si
> для i=2 ,4 , 6, .. . —
> суммы элементов: второго и третьего, четвертого и пятого и так далее. Все Si
> целые и находятся
> в диапазоне 3≤Si≤2⋅109
> .

> Выведите искомую перестановку, если существует; элементы перестановки разделять одним
> пробелом; если таких перестановок несколько, выведите любую. Если таковой перестановки не
> существует, выведите −1

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, перестановка *каких* элементов показана внизу (или элементы надо "придумать" самостоятельно?), и как она соотносится со входом (6+3=9, но дальше идет 3+9=12, а на входе второе число - 9). Это точная формулировка задания, или ваша трактовка? Дайте лучше URL, чтоб понять, что там нужно...

Comment: Это моя трактовка, сейчас дополню вопрос точным заданием

Comment: Числа только натуральные? Или могут быть и отрицательными?

Comment: Только натуральные, в диапазоне *3 <= Si <= 2*10^9* и *3 <= n <= 1000*

Comment: Нет, числа в перестановке. Si - это суммы, n - количество. А сами числа?

Comment: Только натуральные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я опишу алгоритм, а уж код набросайте сами...

Выпишем ряд сумм и ряд чисел перестановки

```
    S1    S2    S3    S4    ...    Sn
a0      a1    a2    a3    a4    ...    an
```

Пусть первое число - `a0=x`. Тогда второе `a1 = S1-x`, `a2 = S2-S1+x` и так далее. Словом, все выражения для `ai` будут представлять собой `S-x` или `x-S`, где `S` - некоторые значения.

Так как числа натуральные, надо просто найти все допустимые значения, для которых это натуральные числа. Надо просто найти минимальное из `S` в выражениях `S-x`, и максимальное - в `x-S`. И посмотреть, имеется ли такое *натуральное* `x`, которое удовлетворяет решению.

Например, для простенького ряда

```
    5     6     5     
x     5-x   x+1   4-x
```

Минимальное для первого случая - 4, т.е. `4-x >= 1`, или `x <= 3`.
Максимальное для второго случая - -1, т.е. `x+1 >= 1`, или `x >= 0`.

Решение есть, `x == 3`, перестановка -

```
 3  2  4  1
```

Вот и всё. Код сами напишете?

Вот код...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> S(n-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)     cin >> S[i*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < (n-1)/2; ++i) cin >> S[i*2+1];

    int M = S[0], m = S[1] - M,   // Первые два значения
        value = 0;
    bool minus = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); ++i)
    {
        value = S[i] - value;

        if (minus = !minus)
        {
            if (M > value) M = value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (m > value) m = value;
        }
    }

    if (M-1 < 1 - m) cout << -1;
    else
    {
        int x = M - 1;   // Выбираем максимально возможный
        cout << x;
        for(int i = 0; i < S.size(); ++i)
            cout << " " << (x = S[i] - x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Звучит довольно сложно, боюсь не смогу код правильно набросать, если бы вы мне и с этим помогли, то цены бы вам не было

Comment: Ну это уже неспортивно... :) URL проверяющей системы есть? А то напишу, где-то опечатка, и начнется испорченный телефон "ааа, не работает!"...

Comment: В этом и проблема что нет, просто pdf файл с заданием и все, вы накидайте пожалуйста, а я если что попытаюсь подправить если что, и преподу сдам как есть, это уже будут мои проблемы, я вас больше не потревожу

Comment: Нет, все же это неспортивно. Все равно выходные. Постарайтесь написать хоть что-то, а то меня совесть мучить будет :) Вот как будет хоть какая-то попытка вашего самостоятельного решения - так и поговорим.

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою твердолобость, но я попробовал реализовать ваш алгоритм вот так, и ничего не получается, просто не понимаю https://dpaste.org/G2dEb

Comment: Вот это и получается то, чего я не хотел, но у меня нет времени сейчас... Вы бы делали, я бы подсказывал - была бы польза: вы бы научились... А так - я кину код, вы сдадите, и все, ни понимания, ни... Постарайтесь хотя бы разобраться, как это работает. См. ответ...

Comment: `почему ее так назвали, непонятно` может быть, ответом может быть только набор всех чисел от 1 до n?

Comment: @MBo Как видите, как пример решения дана вовсе не перестановка чисел от 1 до n...

Comment: @Harry Вот как раз-таки в примере перестановка

Comment: @MBo Да, что-то я уже второй раз за сутки просматриваю очевидную вещь... Была бы URL проверочная - ясно, что увидел бы, что мой способ не работает. Ну, тогда надо из разрешенных вариантов выбрать подходящий. Такое вот эвристическое решение - брать максимально возможное значение, но не уверен, что работает. Что скажете о новом варианте? Для нечетного n можно найти значение x, равное *n(n+1)/2 - сумма Si для нечетных i*, но гарантии, что это будет перестановка, все равно нет. Для четных n не вижу и этого. Может, вы доработаете решение? Я, увы, неполный, но принятый ответ удалить не могу...